# How to format phone number to national format without national prefix using PhoneNumberUtils library?

Tags: android, libphonenumber, phonenumberutils

I'm trying to format a previously E164 formatted phone number into National format without the National Prefix number, I'm using PhoneNumberUtils to do it:

```
public static String getNationalPhone(String phoneE164Formatted) {
    PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
    String phoneNumber = phoneE164Formatted;
    try {
        Phonenumber.PhoneNumber numberProto = phoneUtil.parseAndKeepRawInput(phoneE164Formatted, "");
        phoneNumber = phoneUtil.format(numberProto, PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberFormat.NATIONAL);
    } catch (NumberParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return phoneNumber;
}
```

With that code I'm getting the national prefix I don't want. For example, formatting this number "+526143342293" into national format gave me this result: "01 614 334 22 93", where "01" it's what I want to suppress.

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/brick/phonenumber/blob/master/src/PhoneNumber.php

These answer in php, you can convert into your own.

```
public function getCountryCode()
{
    return (string) $this->phoneNumber->getCountryCode();
}
```

Convert above code will get the national number in desired format.